# What happens to the energy of capacitor or a coil?

Tags: electric-circuits

Imagine we add power to a circuit, stationary power, the resistance will transform the energy to heat, but what will happen to the coil's energy, or to the capacitors energy? They will go back to the source? And decrease the amount of needed energy to the stationary power that we want to add to the circuit?

Comment: Typically it will gradually leak into resistive elements and dissipate as heat unless some poor sucker sticks their finger in first.

Comment: If you could connect an _ideal_ capacitor in parallel with an ideal coil, the circuit could, in principle, oscillate forever, with energy continually bouncing back and forth between them.  A real circuit of course would have resistive losses, and dilectric losses, and radiative losses, and the oscillations would quickly die out.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal capacitor and inductor do not dissipate energy like resistors. The energy delivered to a capacitor and inductor is stored in its electric and magnetic fields, respectively, and are

$$E_{C}=\frac{CV^2}{2}$$

$$E_{L}=\frac{LI^2}{2}$$

The stored energy of each device is returned to the circuit. Since every circuit has some resistance, that energy is generally dissipated as heat. If a circuit has no resistance, the energy of these devices would either be returned to the source, or transferred back and forth between the devices (in oscillation), theoretically forever as @Solomon Slow has commented.

Hope this helps.